# No route matches missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm very new to rails, and am editing code that was originally written by someone else, so I may need a more in-depth response than the average person...

I'm running into this error when I run rake: 
`No route matches {:controller=>"users", :action=>"show", :id=>nil, :format=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]`

The line that appears to be causing the problem is this:

`<%= link_to("My Account", user_path(current_user)) %>`

The link actually works correctly on localhost, but is failing this test at the line "render :template":

```
it "renders new initiative form" do
  assign(:initiative, Initiative.new(location: Location.new,rewards:     [FactoryGirl.create(:reward)]))
  render :template => "initiatives/new.html.erb" (...etc.)
```

Not sure what else is helpful to include here, but the UsersController is:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show 
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

and results from rake routes:

```
    `batch_action_admin_users POST     /admin/users/batch_action(.:format)             admin/users#batch_action
                 admin_users GET      /admin/users(.:format)                          admin/users#index
                             POST     /admin/users(.:format)                          admin/users#create
              new_admin_user GET      /admin/users/new(.:format)                      admin/users#new
             edit_admin_user GET      /admin/users/:id/edit(.:format)                 admin/users#edit
                  admin_user GET      /admin/users/:id(.:format)                      admin/users#show
                             PATCH    /admin/users/:id(.:format)                      admin/users#update
                             PUT      /admin/users/:id(.:format)                      admin/users#update
                             DELETE   /admin/users/:id(.:format)                      admin/users#destroy
 batch_action_admin_comments POST     /admin/comments/batch_action(.:format)          admin/comments#batch_action
              admin_comments GET      /admin/comments(.:format)                       admin/comments#index
                             POST     /admin/comments(.:format)                       admin/comments#create
               admin_comment GET      /admin/comments/:id(.:format)                   admin/comments#show
            new_user_session GET      /users/sign_in(.:format)                        devise/sessions#new
                user_session POST     /users/sign_in(.:format)                        devise/sessions#create
        destroy_user_session DELETE   /users/sign_out(.:format)                       devise/sessions#destroy
     user_omniauth_authorize GET|POST /users/auth/:provider(.:format)                 omniauth_callbacks#passthru {:provider=>/twitter|facebook/}
      user_omniauth_callback GET|POST /users/auth/:action/callback(.:format)          omniauth_callbacks#(?-mix:twitter|facebook)
               user_password POST     /users/password(.:format)                       devise/passwords#create
           new_user_password GET      /users/password/new(.:format)                   devise/passwords#new
          edit_user_password GET      /users/password/edit(.:format)                  devise/passwords#edit
                             PATCH    /users/password(.:format)                       devise/passwords#update
                             PUT      /users/password(.:format)                       devise/passwords#update
    cancel_user_registration GET      /users/cancel(.:format)                         registrations#cancel
           user_registration POST     /users(.:format)                                registrations#create
       new_user_registration GET      /users/sign_up(.:format)                        registrations#new
      edit_user_registration GET      /users/edit(.:format)                           registrations#edit
                             PATCH    /users(.:format)                                registrations#update
                             PUT      /users(.:format)                                registrations#update
                             DELETE   /users(.:format)                                registrations#destroy
                        user GET      /users/:id(.:format)                            users#show`
```

Maybe someone can help?

Comment: Does this happen when you are not logged in ( aka current_user == nil )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Devise login helper to login before you render the template.
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Capybara

Comment: Thanks that was it! I had an inkling, but couldn't get the syntax right.  Very helpful